# CC.Net authentication

Tags: authentication, cruisecontrol.net

I use CruiseControl.Net for my project. Is it possible to configre authentication? I'd like only registered user to be able to force a build.

Regards christian.

Comment: only certain users as in SVN or only certain users as in Windows admin?

Answer (score 2):

Not currently.

I believe the next release of CCNet should include this - version 1.5. View the roadmap here: http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Roadmap